# Is there a way to check if a property has a setter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setter

Is there a way in Python 3.X to check if a class defines a setter method for one of its properties?

Let's say I have the following example :

```py
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self._p = None

  @property
  def my_property(self):
    return self._p

  @my_property.setter
  def my_property(self, new_value):
    self._p = new_value
```

I can check if `my_property` is defined with `hasattr` but I can't find a way to check if the setter is defined.

Here are the two avenues I considered without success :

1. Using `hasattr` to find if a method named `my_property.setter` or something like that exists.
2. Using the `inspect.signature` function to see if the method `my_property` has 2 parameters (self and new_value).

I guess that an extended answer to this question would consider how to detect the presence of a getter as well (making the difference between a property and a getter method because `callable(test.my_property)` returns `False` when we might think it should be `True` because it is a method).

Comment: What if the attribute is not a `property`? It's possible to set it but it doesn't have a `setter`. In that case, would you want the check to be positive (as if it has a setter) or negative?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python (almost a duplicate as the answer is somewhere there in the accepted...)

Comment: "when we might think it should be True because it is a method)." – no, `test.my_property` is neither a method nor a property. `Test.my_property` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test if the `.fset` attribute is `None` or not:

```
>>> Test.my_property.fset is not None  # has a setter
True
>>> Test.my_property.fdel is not None  # has no deleter
False
```

The same way you can also test if it has a getter (via `.fget`). To test whether the attribute is a property at all, you can test `isinstance(Test.my_property, property)`.

Make sure to always call these on the class level, and not on an individual instance.